# How can I set the resolution and rotate the screen of an app launched with startx

Tags: 20.04, xorg, display-resolution

I have a Ubuntu Server 20.04 installed on which I added `xubuntu-desktop` and disabled it from starting with `systemctl set-default multi-user`, I just needed the libraries that came with it to launch my app.

So now I have an installation that is booting in CLI only mode.

After logging in, I am launching an `appimage` app using `startx myapp.appimage`.

My problem is that it is not using the full size of the monitor, but only a square in the middle, and I have another problem trying to rotate that screen, because my monitor is in portrait orientation.

I've search a while for those answers, getting close, but not quite there yet.

People say to try `xrandr`, for example `xrandr -q` is supposed to list your video outputs, but it returns `Can't open display`. I may have to create a `.xsession` or `.xinitrc` file and run `xrandr` in the `startx`? I'm lost...

I've also seen people talking about adding options to the monitor section of `xorg.conf`. This file doesn't exist on the filesystem, but there is the alternative in `xorg.conf.d`, there, I can't find the section they are talking about, seems like I would have to create it myself, but that would mean hardcoding the settings to this specific monitor no?

My graphic chip is: `VGA compatible controller Intel Corporation HD Graphics 500`, do I need to install a driver?

By the way, if I let the xubuntu desktop start, it seems to be fullscreen and of the right resolution.

This app will be a kiosk app, so that's why I don't want the desktop.

I wish it would be as simple as setting some `startx` parameters.

Edit: I made some progress.

Instead of using `startx myapp.appimage`, I created a `.xinitrc` file and in that file I wrote:

```
xrandr
myapp.appimage
```

then launch it using `startx > output.log`.

This launches my app and in the logs, I see the output of xrandr, I have an output called "default" with a max resolution of 1920*1080.

When I change that `xrandr` command to `xrandr --output default --rotate left` nothing different happens, no error in the logs, but the app is still not rotated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

`startx` by itself launches what's in `.xinitrc`, you can override that and specify what file to launch, like how I was doing with `startx myapp.appimage`, in that case it's ignoring `.xinitrc`.

The solution was to update `.xinitrc` with:

```
xrandr --output DP-1 --rotate left --fb 1080x1920
myapp.appimage
```

but that's not all.

I had to remove `nomodeset` from GRUB so I could run (without errors):

```
Xorg :0 -configure
cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

These 2 commands discovered my monitor and all the outputs ports, that made `xrandr` work with `DP-1`.

Then, calling `startx` (without specifying my app) would run `.xinitrc` and rotate the screen, set the resolution and launch my app.

It is likely that if I didn't add `nomodeset` to GRUB I would have found the solution earlier.